# New page with info based on a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, cordova

Is it possible to have a link with an id within it such as

```
<li><a href='newpage.html' id='12'>Some title</a></li>
```

When you click on the link a new page html page opens and on that new page, information found in a database with the id of 12 (as found in the link) will be displayed using external style sheets etc. Can this be done with html css javascript and json?

P.S I know how to do this with PHP however I want this to be done in my mobile app so the actual page cannot be a `.php` page

Comment: Why do you need JSON for this? Are you working with some API that serves JSON?

Comment: The info is coming from a database to retrieve the info I am returning Json

Comment: If not PHP, what language are you using? Regardless, I feel that the front-end should be the same, "newpage.html?id=12".  It sounds like you're not sure how to interpret the URL parameter on the back-end.

Comment: A side note: Your ID really shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: So if the front end is newpage.html?id=12 how will I be able to pull the 12 from id to pull the 12th item in my db and return the info to an html page not a php one. I know how to do it in a php page not in an html one

Answer (score 1):

With phone gap you can still call out to php pages using ajax, so write your database quesry in a php file on your server and call out too it.

```
  <li><a href='newpage.html?id=12' class="clickButton">Some title</a></li>
```

On your new page

```
 function linkParam(name){
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
                var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
                var results = regex.exec (window.location.href);
                if (results == null)
                    return "";
                    else
                    return results[1];  
            }

           var linkP = linkParam("id");

        $.get('http://yourserver.com/ajax/your.php?id='+linkP, function(data) {
          var result = $('.result').html(data);
        });
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: I read that apps cannot read php pages its an app being developed with phone gap

Comment: Thats cool I didnt know you where using phone gap worth noting in your description. So the javascript would work for you also you could call out using javascript to a php page with ajax, this definantly works with phone gap I will change my response accrodingly.

Comment: ok I understand the top half of your answer with the remote call but that isn't puting the info on a new page but in a new state correct? I want the information in a new page to solve some History management issues.

Comment: Edited again hopefully this should sort you if not you might have to use a bit of brain to work out the rest ;)